# Peer to Peer connection using RTMFP

Tags: air, rtmfp

I am trying to implement peer to peer communication using RTMFP and NetStream.
When connecting with the server I am able to get My own peer ID.But Is there any way to get the other connected Client's Peer ID for direct communication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to manage Peer ID's manually with serverside logic, for example linking them to nicknames and assign them to groups/chatrooms using a database. You can then request the Peer ID from the server by nickname or request a group of Peer ID's by group id.